# counting max number of lines for pre element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<pre>` html element and a text box append to it. when I write in the text box the text appears on the pre element (like a terminal window) but my problem is that when the texts that I enter reach to the end of the pre element height they new coming text disapears from the bottom. you can imagine it as a message box without navigation so the coming new lines go out of the scene and we can only see the old ones. I am wondering how I can count the maximum line per page and remove the first added one from the top? do you know any example of work? and that is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2133/ but what we enter does not appear in pre element because I wrote some ajax post server side that I could not write them in jsfiddle

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns" style="background: #222; height: 70vh;">
  <pre id="terminalPre" width="2">
    <code id="terminal" style="color: #fff; padding: 1em;" ></code>
  </pre>
  <input type="text" id="textInput" name="" style="background: #222; position: absolute; bottom: 0; color: #fff;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: jsfiddle please? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: In ur JSFidle link There is no JQuery to show it on <pre> please update the link with your code

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you solve it with CSS.
You could add a `div` with the style `overflow:hidden` and then use jQuery to scroll it to the bottom.

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s4FyM/1/

Needed jquery to scroll the div:

```
$('.box').scrollTop($('.box')[0].scrollHeight);
```